# Show documents stored procedure -- how to select twice-approved documents.

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a scenario that when any user first uploads a document, it then goes for approval. First it goes to a supervisor.  When a supervisor approves/rejects documents, only approved documents go to a manager.  Then, when a manager approves/rejects documents, only approved documents go to a director for final approval.

Here's the current stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ALLDOCUMNETS]
   AS
 begin

  SELECT     dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID, 
   dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 
   dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded, 
    dbo.Userss.Email as UserEmail,
    dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 

    dbo.DocType.DocType as Document,
      dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as UploadedBy, 
      dbo.Approval.AppoveBy, dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
     FROM         dbo.DocumentInfo INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 
        inner JOIN dbo.Userss on Userss.UserName =dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy inner 
           JOIN
                  dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID =     
         dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
         INNER JOIN
                  dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = dbo.DocType.DocTypeID

              end
```

This sp's output looks like this:

[image: sp output]

In the above, kanez is the manager, and sundus is the supervisor.

I want only kanez approved documents to show to the director for final approval.  Now, both supervisor and manager-approved documents are going to the director, but I want to show only manager-approved documents to the director.

How can I do this?

Tables
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you provide sample data/ table structure then i will give better solution than this.

any way below solution will work if it is not working then i will give another solution(if send structure).

i assumed DocId is unique for all documents.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ALLDOCUMNETS]
   AS
 begin
;with x as 
  (SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID
  ORDER BY dbo.Approval.seqno desc) ID,   dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID,
   dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 
   dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded, 
dbo.Userss.Email as UserEmail,
dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 

dbo.DocType.DocType as Document,
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as UploadedBy, 
  dbo.Approval.AppoveBy, dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
 FROM         dbo.DocumentInfo INNER JOIN
              dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 
    inner JOIN dbo.Userss on Userss.UserName =dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy inner 
       JOIN
              dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID =     
     dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID INNER JOIN
              dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
     INNER JOIN
              dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = dbo.DocType.DocTypeID

          end) SELECT DocumentID,DocumentName,FileUploaded,UserEmail,
          Department,Document,UploadedBy,AppoveBy,Status from x where X.Id=1
```

---

table structure is not good.

change updateddate in to seqno desc in previous query,

then you will get the last updated person record what ever he is

Comment: (I removed my previous comment, because YOUR ANSWER makes his goal clearer, than the question did.)  Good work... but won't the above give him manager approvals WHEN THEY EXIST, but otherwise give him SUPERVISOR approvals too?  To give him **ONLY** manager-approved docs, modify your logic to select docs with *2 different approvals*.  Using the above, report `where X.Id=1` only when `where X.Id=2` **ALSO EXISTS** (JOIN to that, for example).  Or: JOIN to a SELECT with a GROUP BY, and give that GROUP BY a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, or a `HAVING MIN(dbo.Approval.seqno) <> MAX(dbo.Approval.seqno)`